# grep, sed of awk a file for unique values then count the results

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a huge log that contains 100,000s of lines xml transactions

many lines contain duplicate entries eg Account id's I would like to grep/sed or awk those account id's sort and show unique results or count it.

Below is the pattern I am trying to grep/sed/awk

```
<Account Id="123456789012">
```

so far I've tried the following:

```
sort 20150229.log | grep '<Account Id="*">' | uniq | wc -l
```

but i get 0 results....

Please advise

thanks

Comment: Edit your question to include some concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you but at a glance - `*` means `zero or more repetitions of the preceding regexp segment`, you should use `[^"]*` instead of `*`. There are other issues with your approach too though.

Comment: Use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Comment: `sort` itself can produce unique lines for you. Try `grep -E '<Account Id="[^"]+"' acct.txt | sort -u | wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

## Counting unique lines in a text file

I have an alias for this kind of thing since I run into it so often:

```
alias cnt='sort -if |uniq -ic |sort -ifn'  # case insensitive
alias CNT='sort |uniq -c |sort -n'         # strict, case sensitive
```

This sorts the input (`-i` ignores nonprinting characters, `-f` ignores case) and then uses `uniq` (which can only handle pre-sorted data, `-i` is case insensitive, `-c` counts repetitions), then sorts the counts numerically (`-n` for numeric).  (Note: the final case outputted by `cnt` may be more capitalized than expected due to how the commands rectify case differences.)

Invoke this like:

```
cat 20150229.log |cnt
```

Arguments to `cnt` will be passed to the final `sort` command, so you can use flags like `-r` to reverse the sorting.  I recommend running it through `tail` or something like `awk '$1 > 5'` to eliminate all of the small entries.

## Parsing XML

The above works great for random text files like logs.  Parsing HTML or XML is a [Bad Idea™](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) unless you have full knowledge of the exact formatting you'll be parsing.

That said, you have a `grep` query with a flawed regular expression to match XML:

> ```
> grep '<Account Id="*">'
> ```

This matches `<Account Id="">` (as well as `<Account Id=">` and `<Account Id=""">`, which you may not want), but it won't match your example `<Account Id="123456789012">`.  The `*` in that regex looks for zero or more of the previous character (`"`).  Here is [a more thorough explanation](https://regex101.com/r/gF1yY0/1).

You need a `.` in there to represent any character ([explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/gF1yY0/2)):

```
grep '<Account Id=".*">'
```

Additionally, `grep` won't match full lines unless you give it the `-x` flag, and I'm guessing you don't want that because it will then fail if there is surrounding whitespace (see the above Bad Idea™ link!).  Here is a cheaper version of that grep, making use of my alias:

```
grep '<Account Id=' 20150229.log |cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to use a parser. I like `XML::Twig` for this sort of job, because you can purge as you go.

But something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %count_of;

sub count_unique_id {
    my ( $twig, $account ) = @_;
    my $id = $account->att('id'); 
    print "New ID: $id\n" unless $count_of{$id};
    $count_of{$id}++;
    $twig -> purge; 
}

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( twig_handlers => { 'Account' => \&count_unique_id } );
$twig -> parsefile ( 'your_file.xml'); 

foreach my $id ( keys %count_of ) { 
   print "$id => $count_of{$id}\n";
}

print "There were ", scalar keys %count_of, " unique IDs\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're confident about the regularity of the XML and do not feel the need to use an XML-aware tool, then the following may well suffice, and has some advantages, e.g. it does not require `gawk` while still being somewhat tolerant of small variations:

```
awk -v RS='<' '/^Account +Id *=/ { sub(/^[^=]*= *"/,""); sub(/".*/, ""); print}' |
sort | uniq
```

If you want to avoid the sort, then you can easily modify the awk script, e.g. as follows:

```
awk -v RS='<' '
 /^Account +Id *=/ { sub(/^[^=]*= *"/,""); sub(/".*/, ""); m[$0]}
 END {for (i in m) {print i}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us any testable sample input and expected output so it's a guess but this MAY be what you want:

```
awk 'sub(/.*<Account Id="/,"") && sub(/".*/,"") && !seen[$0]++' 20150229.log
```